# How to modify all lines in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, terminal

I have a file called `index.js` with more than 200 lines :

```
AcademicCapIcon.svelte
AdjustmentsIcon.svelte
AnnotationIcon.svelte
ArchiveIcon.svelte
...
```

I'd like to change this to the following:

```
import AcademicCapIcon from './dir1/dir2/AcademicCapIcon.svelte'
import AdjustmentsIcon from './dir1/dir2/AdjustmentsIcon.svelte'
import AnnotationIcon from './dir1/dir2/AnnotationIcon.svelte'
import ArchiveIcon from './dir1/dir2/ArchiveIcon.svelte'
...
```

Is there any way I can do it from a terminal with one liner or shell/bash script?

I did like the following but I'm stuck:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/import /' index.js && sed -n 's/$/ from && bla bla.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed "s:\(.*\)\.svelte:import \1 from './dir1/dir2/&':" index.js
import AcademicCapIcon from './dir1/dir2/AcademicCapIcon.svelte'
import AdjustmentsIcon from './dir1/dir2/AdjustmentsIcon.svelte'
import AnnotationIcon from './dir1/dir2/AnnotationIcon.svelte'
import ArchiveIcon from './dir1/dir2/ArchiveIcon.svelte'
...
```

If happy with the result, add back the `-i`

Comment: I'm amazed. Thank you for your help. You are my today's hero.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk -i inplace -v q="'" '{ split($0, arr, "."); print "import " arr[1] " from " q "./dir1/dir2/" $0 q }' index.js
import AcademicCapIcon from './dir1/dir2/AcademicCapIcon.svelte'
import AdjustmentsIcon from './dir1/dir2/AdjustmentsIcon.svelte'
import AnnotationIcon from './dir1/dir2/AnnotationIcon.svelte'
import ArchiveIcon from './dir1/dir2/ArchiveIcon.svelte'
```